# Android - getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled() crashes app, only on small French screen

Tags: java, android, localization, nexus-4

So I am in the process of localizing my app for different languages, starting with French, and have come across a bizarre problem.

Upon creating an activity, I call `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`.  This works fine when testing on my Nexus 7 in both English and French, and works fine on my Nexus 4 when using the default (English) resources.

However, if I try to start the activity in question on my Nexus 4 in French (i.e. the phone is set to French, though the problem also occurs if I try to force the app into French regardless), the app crashes, with Eclipse telling me there was a null pointer exception.  I determined the problem to be the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` call.

Passing `false` instead of `true` also crashes.  Calling `getActionBar()` without making any further calls does not crash the app.  The app is set up according to a Master-Detail flow (so the core of the app are two Activity-Fragment pairs, one List and one Detail), which I assume is why the Nexus 7 version can work fine despite the Nexus 4 version crashing.

I have double-checked my `values` and `values-fr` folders, and I am sure there are no missing or extra resources in `values-fr`.

Any clues as to why this might be happening?

Here is what LogCat tells me:

```
04-27 15:13:44.968: D/AndroidRuntime(4244): Shutting down VM
04-27 15:13:44.968: W/dalvikvm(4244): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41429930)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ca.hachesoftware.soilbearingcapacity/ca.hachesoftware.soilbearingcapacity.ScreenDetailActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at ca.hachesoftware.soilbearingcapacity.ScreenDetailActivity.onCreate(ScreenDetailActivity.java:34)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-27 15:13:44.978: E/AndroidRuntime(4244):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Posting the stack trace would help.

Comment: Added the log info above.

Comment: What is line 34 of `ScreenDetailActivity`?

Comment: getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Then `getActionBar()` is returning `null`. Note that if you are using ActionBarSherlock, I think you should be calling `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Hm... could this be related to the fact that, for some reason, the entire Android interface looks a bit different when I switch to French?  The colors change from black-blue to black-green and the fields have white backgrounds and look boxier.  In any case, I am not using any extensions, just stock Android functions.

Comment: That means you're not getting a reference to an ActionBar. Check to make sure you've not overridden your Activity style in a `-fr` resource folder of some sort to a theme that does NOT include an ActionBar.

Comment: The `styles.xml` file in both `values` and `values-fr` are identical.  The only other localized files are the `string.xml` files, which are also identical except for the content of individual strings.

Comment: @GarrickW If they're identical, why have them in both folders?

Comment: So I deleted the styles.xml file in values-fr and, for whatever reason, suddenly everything works as intended.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for those who are interested, while I didn't discover the reason behind the problem, I found that I could prevent it.  What I did when I started localizing was copy the entire `values` folder and append the language code, making it `values-fr`.  There were two files in the folder, `strings.xml` and `styles.xml`, the latter of which were identical in both the default and `-fr` versions.

Deleting `styles.xml` from `values-fr`, but leaving it intact in `values`, resolved the problem (and also prevented the French interface from looking different from the English version).

Answer (score 0):

Ensure 2 things:
1) You have suppressed the Lint error by having  @SuppressLint("NewApi") on the top of onCreate method. (Which I guess probably you have already done!)
2) You must include minSdk specified in the Android manifest file.
Keep these lines: (just right after the manifest tag)

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Hope that helps!